# How can I upgrade my JQuery that will save last function when Post or Refresh page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, save

With help of "@Dimitar Dimitrov" I have create this javascript that changes values after click on link.
Here is JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/3uqF2/19/

Here is code of function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".my-link").on("click", function() { 
        $(".status").hide();
        var linkId = $(this).data("id");
        $("." + linkId).show();
    });
});
```

My Question is, how can I upgrade it, so when I refresh page or click on post (e.g. search button), my value that I click (e.g. "Eng", watch link of Fiddle) **saves**, so when I again click on refresh or post, this link would stay until I click another one. Now when I click refresh or post it always return to first link "Slo" (watch link of Fiddle).

!Note: I have put this code in my _Layout.cshtml so I can use it on all pages.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try saving it in a cookie :

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
//getting the value of the cookie
if(document.cookie!=""){
     $(".status").hide();
    var linkId = document.cookie;
    $("." + linkId).show();
}
$(".my-link").on("click", function() { 
    $(".status").hide();
    var linkId = $(this).data("id");
 //setting the value of the cookie
    document.cookie=linkId;
    $("." + linkId).show();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an action when the user is leaving the page by binding a remove call on `<body/>`:

```
$('body').bind('remove', function(event) {
    $.get('/api/leaving_page');
});
```

Comment: I have try it, but still don't work, you can try it on fiddle, and try to refresh page.