# Need jQuery remember state of menu on page refresh

Tags: jquery, cookies, menu

I thinks jQuery cookies should sloves my problem, but I have no idea how it works exactly...

here is JS:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
                var e = document.getElementById(id);
                var f = document.getElementById('obsah');
                if (e.style.display === 'block' && f.style.width === '83%') {
                    $("#sidebar").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        f.style.width = '98%';
                    }, 200);
                } else {
                    $("#sidebar").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
                    f.style.width = '83%';
                }
            }
```

here is button

```
 <span onclick="toggle_visibility('sidebar');" class="icon_bar" style="float: left; margin: 10px 0 15px 0;"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i></span>
```

Comment: Need jQuery remember state of which element. Elaborate your question

Comment: It's very simple my dear boy https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: I need it to remember this:
$("#sidebar").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
f.style.width = '83%';

Comment: i think you mean you need the page to remember the state of the span wait i'll write the code test it and answer :)

Comment: I tried it with that cookies, but probably I am doing something wrong... And code is too long to show you it in comment here :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today i finally solve it:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
                var e = document.getElementById(id);
                var f = document.getElementById('obsah');
                if (e.style.display === 'block' && f.style.width === '83%') {
                    $("#sidebar").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        f.style.width = '98%';
                    }, 200);
                    $.cookie("menuState", "closed");
                } else {
                    $("#sidebar").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
                    f.style.width = '83%';
                    $.cookie("menuState", "opened");
                }
            }
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var h = document.getElementById('obsah');
                if ($.cookie("menuState") === "opened") {
                    $("#sidebar").show();
                    h.style.width = '83%';
                } else if ($.cookie("menuState") === "closed") {
                    $("#sidebar").hide();
                    h.style.width = '98%';
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanna consider using [HTML5 Web Storage Objects](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) .

Quote from W3Schools page:
"HTML5 Web Storage provides two new objects for storing data on the client:

`window.localStorage` - stores data with no expiration date

`code.sessionStorage` - stores data for one session (data is lost when the tab is closed) "

In your case you might find `sessionStorage` as the most useful one: [example code](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_session)

Answer (score 0):

**here is the preparation and getting of the state of the object:**

```
 var state="visible";//set the initial state of the object
        $(document).ready(function(){
        if(document.cookie!=""){
        var tmp =document.cookie.split(';');
            id=tmp[1];
            state=tmp[0];
            if(state=="unvisible"){
                $("#"+id).hide();
            }
            else{
                 $("#"+id).show();
            }
        }
        });
```

**here is the function :**

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   //replace this line by your code you get the idea ;)
   $("#"+id).fadeToggle("fast","linear");
   //
        state=(state=="visible")?"unvisible":"visdible";
        document.cookie=state+";"+id;
  }
```

Comment: Still it isnt remeber. Even if I corrcet visdible to visible :(

Comment: yeah sorry :/ i will see what i can do (and sorry about the typo)

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: sad to say i didnt find a way to replace the use of cookie funny thing i already answer an other gentlman who had a a similar situation here is the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24927981/how-can-i-upgrade-my-jquery-that-will-save-last-function-when-post-or-refresh-pa/